# solving matrices using Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra

So I searched the in internet looking for programs with **Cramer's Rule** and there were some few, but apparently these examples were for fixed matrices only like 2x2 or 4x4.

However, I am looking for a way to solve a NxN Matrix. So I started and reached the point of asking the user for the size of the matrix and asked the user to input the values of the matrix but then I don't know how to move on from here.

As in I guess my next step is to apply Cramer's rule and get the answers but I just don't know how.[This is the step I'm missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ans.png). can anybody help me please?

Comment: To improve this question, add a Minimum Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to calculate the determinant of your equations system matrix - that is the matrix, that consists of the coefficients (from the left-hand side of the equations) - let it be **D**.

Then, to calculate the value of a certain variable, you need to take the matrix of your system (from the previous step), replace the coefficients of the corresponding column with constant terms (from the right-hand side), calculate the determinant of resulting matrix - let it be **C**, and divide **C** by **D**.

A bit more about the replacement from the previous step: say, your matrix if 3x3 (as in the image) - so, you have a system of equations, where every *a* coefficient is multiplied by *x*, every *b* - by *y*, and every *c* by *z*, and *d*s are the constant terms. So, to calculate *y*, you replace those coefficients that are multiplied by *y* - *b*s in this case, with *d*s.

You perform the second step for every variable and your system gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#C
Although the specific example deals with a 4X4 matrix the code is written to accommodate any size square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is calculate the determinant. Cramer's rule is just for the determinant of a `NxN` matrix

if N is not big, you can use the Cramer's rule(see code below), which is quite straightforward.  However, this method is not efficient; if your N is big, you need to resort to other methods, such as [lu decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)

Assuming your data is double, and result can be hold by double.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
double det(double * matrix, int n) {
    if( 1 >= n ) return matrix[ 0 ];
    double *subMatrix = (double*)malloc(( n - 1 )*( n - 1 ) * sizeof(double));
    double result = 0.0;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j ) {
            for( int k = 0; k < i; ++k )
                subMatrix[ j*( n - 1 ) + k ] = matrix[ ( j + 1 )*n + k ];
            for( int k = i + 1; k < n; ++k )
                subMatrix[ j*( n - 1 ) + ( k - 1 ) ] = matrix[ ( j + 1 )*n + k ];
        }
        if( i % 2 == 0 )
            result += matrix[ 0 * n + i ] * det(subMatrix, n - 1);
        else
            result -= matrix[ 0 * n + i ] * det(subMatrix, n - 1);
    }
    free(subMatrix);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    double matrix[ ] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,6,4,8,3,1,1,2 };
    printf("%lf\n", det(matrix, 4));
    return 0;
}
```